# Symfony2's AccessDeniedHandlerInterface to automatically redirect unauthorized users

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

When implementing an [AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authorization/AccessDeniedHandlerInterface.html) to catch any [AccessDeniedExceptions](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AccessDeniedException.html) is it possible to access the role of the user in order to determine an appropriate RedirectResponse route?

I want to direct people who aren't logged in to one place, and people that are logged in but don't have the permissions to another place, instead of just getting a 403 page.

Answer (score 3):

One solution to the problem is to pass the [SecurityContext](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContext.html) object as an argument to the `AccessDeniedHandlerInterface` in the `config.yml` file like so.

```
//config.yml

kernel.listener.access_denied_listener:
    class: Path\To\Your\Class
    arguments: [@security.context]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: handle }
```

Doing this allows the `handle()` method access to the token representing the current user authentication. From this the appropriate re-routing can take place.

```
namespace Path\To\Your\Class;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authorization\AccessDeniedHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AccessDeniedListener implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
    {
        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            return new RedirectResponse('user_route');
        }
    }
}
```