# Symfony Handle Not Working

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, registration

So I followed this tutorial to force incomplete users to register if they are coming from Oauth and don't have an email in their facebook/twitter accounts.

http://alexfu.it/2012/11/09/force-incomplete-users-to-complete-registration/

In the last step there is a handle function and it doesn't seem to ever be triggering. Is there something else that's missing?

```
namespace FYP\UserBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authorization\AccessDeniedHandlerInterface;

class UserIncompleteListener implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{
    protected $security;
    protected $router;

    public function __construct($security, $router)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
    {   
        if(!is_null($this->security->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles()) &&  $this->security->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles() == array('ROLE_INCOMPLETE_USER')) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('register_complete'));
        }
    }
}
```

Config:

```
fyp_user.access_denied.handler:
        class:           FYP\UserBundle\Listener\UserIncompleteListener
        arguments:
            security:    @security.context
            router:      @router
```

Security:

```
 firewalls:
        main:
            access_denied_handler: fyp_user.access_denied.handler
```

Heres my firewall:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        access_denied_handler: fyp_user.access_denied.handler
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        oauth:
            failure_path: /login
            login_path:  /login
            check_path: /connect_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            remember_me:  true
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /login
            resource_owners:
                facebook: "/external-login/check-facebook"
                paypal: "/external-login/check-paypal"
                amazon: "/external-login/check-amazon"
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: app.provider.oauth
            remember_me:
                key:      %secret%  # pararmeter
                lifetime: 31536000  # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
                always_remember_me: true
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check
            success_handler: authentication_handler
            failure_handler: authentication_handler
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            remember_me:  true
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        switch_user: { role: ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, parameter: _new_user }
        remember_me:
            key:      %secret%  # pararmeter
            lifetime: 31536000  # 365 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
            always_remember_me: true
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `kernel.event_listener` tag from your service definition. For some reason, the blog post author did not add it as well.

Your service definition should actually look like this:

```
fyp_user.access_denied.handler:
    class:           FYP\UserBundle\Listener\UserIncompleteListener
    arguments:
        security:    @security.context
        router:      @router
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: handle }
```

For more info, take a look at Symfony docs on [events and listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082107/405097).

Comment: Thank you, I added that and read the documentation but it still wont trigger.